# What is the total number of combinations of n elements when repetition is allowed?

Tags: combinations

Say we use four elements where three elements are same and one is different A,A,A,B now total number of possible combinations are
A,
B,
AA,
AB,
AAA,
AAB,
AAAB,
So ans=7

Comment: Doesn't $BA$ count as well?

Comment: The general method to solve problems like this is the method of generating functions.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_function_.28OGF.29

Comment: No BA doesn't count we are taking combinations not permutations.